# Using Assembly global variable in C

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, global-variables

Trying to compile this code in a.s:

```
section .bss
global _start
global TestVar
TestVar:    RESB 4

section .text
extern main

_start:
```

and this code in b.c:

```
extern int TestVar;

void test2(int x, int y)
    {
      int z = TestVar;
      x = z + y;
      y = 1;
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      return 0;
    }
```

with this makefile:

```
all:    test

test:   a.o b.o
    ld -melf_i386 a.o b.o -o test
a.o:    a.s
    nasm -f elf  a.s -o a.o
b.o:    b.c
    gcc -m32 -Wall -g b.c -o b.o

.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    rm -f *.o test
```

running the makefile produces:

```
m@m-All-Series:~/testFolder$ make
nasm -f elf  a.s -o a.o
gcc -m32 -Wall -g b.c -o b.o
/tmp/ccjymll2.o: In function `test2':
/home/m/testFolder/b.c:5: undefined reference to `TestVar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:9: recipe for target 'b.o' failed
make: *** [b.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
also, main is there just because if it isn't - the compiler says there is an undefined reference to main in _start in crt1.o, main will never be called, only test2, I don't know if that matters so I included that info as well.

Comment: You are missing the `-c` switch for `gcc` telling it to compile but not link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the compiler's `-c` option if you want to compile a C source into an object file. Without it, gcc tries to go on linking, which is not what you want. E.g.

```
b.o: b.c
       gcc -c -m32 -Wall -g b.c
```

should get you a bit further.

Comment: yes, this solved it.. but now when I try to run the executable it says: "bash: ./test No such file or directory"
I should also say that in my real code I'm using C functions, so I added -lc to the linking. I'm on 64 bit windows 7. what could be the problem? Or should I mark this question as answered and open a new one? thank you.

Comment: @user3001010 Your Makefile is too complex. The compiler will automatically invoke the linker with options to link with the C library and to create an executable. Your `test` program is very likely an object file, not an executable. Try replacing `ld` with `gcc`.

Comment: like so- gcc -m32 -g -Wall -o test a.o b.o ?
if so, then this causes:
a.s:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib32/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib32/crt1.o:

Comment: @user3001010 Why do you need `_start`? In your code it does nothing. Since all symbols beginning with an underscore are reserved for the implementation, you are not allowed to use it in your code. Try removing it.

Comment: my actual code does use _start, that's where my program starts(I just didn't add the code after _start in the question).

Comment: @user3001010 If you let gcc link, the entry point will be main, not _start. What is your objective? If it's only declaring an external variable, then you don't need to define _start.

Comment: my objective is to write a program that starts at the assembly file a.s
how do I do that with gcc as a linker? should I delete _start and use _main instead? thank you for the help btw.

Comment: @user3001010 That's backwards. It's much easier to let the C runtime call main, and then in main you can call a function in a.s. That way you don't have to forcibly change the entry function. You could even define the main function in a.s instead of in b.c. Note that the symbol should be spelled `main` and not `_main` if you do this.